# Displaying data from mysql from datepicker

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need some suggestions/help with my code.
Code:

```
<form method='post' action='' autocomplete="off">
Start Date <input type='text' class='dateFilter' name='fromDate' value='<?php if(isset($_POST['fromDate'])) echo 
$_POST['fromDate']; ?>'>
End Date <input type='text' class='dateFilter' name='endDate' value='<?php if(isset($_POST['endDate'])) echo 
$_POST['endDate']; ?>'>
<input type='submit' name='but_search' value='Search'>
</form>
```

```
 <table border='1' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;margin-top: 20px;'>
   <tr>
     <th>EmployeeName</th>
     <th>WorkDate</th>
     <th>WorkType</th>
     <th>CustomerName</th>
   </tr>

   <?php
   $emp_query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE 1";

   // Date filter
   if(isset($_POST['but_search'])){
      $fromDate = $_POST['fromDate'];
      $endDate = $_POST['endDate'];

      if(!empty($fromDate) && !empty($endDate)){
         $emp_query .= " and workdate 
                      between '".$fromDate."' and '".$endDate."' ";
      }
    }

    // Sort
    $emp_query .= " ORDER BY id ASC";
    $employeesRecords = mysqli_query($conn,$emp_query);

    // Check records found or not
    if(mysqli_num_rows($employeesRecords) > 0){
      while($empRecord = mysqli_fetch_assoc($employeesRecords)){
        $id = $empRecord['id'];
        $empName = $empRecord['username'];
        $date_of_join = $empRecord['workdate'];
        $gender = $empRecord['worktype'];
        $email = $empRecord['customername'];


        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>". $empName ."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $date_of_join ."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $gender ."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $email ."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td colspan='4'>No record found.</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
  </table>
 </div>
```

When i select dateFrom and dateTo, everything works like a charm and form shows me records from db between two dates, but what i need:
I want to display data for specific user.
Example: I choose Employee Name > Micheal from  and form shows me data for Micheal only, when i choose David, shows only for David not all employees.
How can i do this?

I have database with 3 tables: employees, accounts and customers.

Under employees i have columns: id, username, workdate, startdate and enddate.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. **First**: You should add a select option to your form, and on each row
   set the id as value.
2. **Second**: You need to get the id with: $id = $_POST['id'];
3. **Third**: Finally, you need to change your query to:

> SELECT *  FROM employees  WHERE workdate BETWEEN '".$fromDate."'
>   AND'".$endDate."'  AND id = $id

Comment: And don't forget to use prepared statements -- this is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: And only select the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: Thanks, this one is done. I got another question, i hope you can help me: Im trying to display data from database for each user, this is what i get: https://imgur.com/7HR6pDJ - but this is what i want to get when i press View button: https://imgur.com/eCsVAhp (all single user, in this case - Testing user, information in this popup). First record, then second and etc in popup, not like in first image.

Comment: @doughtylatvia i recommend you mark this question as resolved and do a new one, after that , let me know the link to check it out.